# Cron spamming because of renice

Tags: shell-script, cron

I have a bash script that I execute using cron.
The script begins like this:

```
#! /bin/bash

DIR=/home/pi/bin/run

renice 19 -p $$
ionice -c 3 -p $$
:
```

Now, every time cron runs this script it sends me a mail:

```
/home/pi/bin/run/test-script:
6461 (process ID) old priority 0, new priority 19
```

When I comment out the `renice` command the script executes without a problem.

I don't want cron to send me a mail that the script reniced itself because that's by design.

What's going on and/or how can I fix this?

Comment: What happens if you start the script directly in the shell?

Comment: That's interesting:  $ ./00-test-script ....
9395 (process ID) old priority 0, new priority 19    .....  The script outputs the line...

Comment: But there is no `line 31: i: command not found` error message?

Comment: Can you just include the whole script. There's more there that would seem to be the issue than what you're showing us here.

Comment: I edited the question because there appeared to be two different causes.

Comment: I removed the non-relevant parts because it was flagged as off-topic. The accepted answer now fully answers the question. How this will satisfy people.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try using these forms of `renice` and `ionice`:

```
$ renice 19 -p $$ >/dev/null 2>&1
$ ionice -c3 -p $$ >/dev/null 2>&1
```

Comment: Yes, that does the trick.